# solving linear gradient PDE

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, vector-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ be a function that satisfies the equation:

$$\nabla^T f = - (\nabla^T \phi ) f $$
where $\phi:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ is some given function and $\nabla^T$ is the column partial derivatives operator.

Then obviousely $f(x)=k e^{-\phi(x)}$ solves the equation.

Assume now that we have the equation:
$$Q \nabla^T f = - (\nabla^T \phi ) f $$
for some symmetric positive definite matrix $Q$.
Can it be solved similarly?

Comment: the RHS is not a scaler. $-(\nabla^T \phi) f$ is an n dimensional vector

Comment: Do you know how to solve $\nabla^T f = A f$? :) Then if $Q$ is invertable then $\nabla^T f = -Q^{-1} \nabla^T \phi f$. I think the one-dimensional case is too familiar. $y'=py$.

Comment: yes but then $A$ is a matrix valued function of $x$, i.e. $\nabla ^T f= A(x) f$.  how to integrate?

Comment: mmmmmm, I think that I am stuck. Will think on that. This is an interesting question. By the way $A(x)$ will be a vector not a matrix. :)

Comment: yes it is a vector. sorry!

Comment: I am trying to think of some appropriate change of variables

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the equation can be solved similarly. To solve the equation
$$
Q \nabla^T f = -(\nabla^T \phi) f
$$
we can use the concept of a change of variables, along with a little bit of intuition.

We have a symmetric positive definite matrix $Q$. Let's use the fact that we can find an orthogonal matrix $P$ and a diagonal matrix $D$ such that $Q = PDP^T$. The columns of $P$ are eigenvectors of $Q$, and the diagonal entries of $D$ are the corresponding eigenvalues. As $Q$ is symmetric and positive-definite, all eigenvalues are positive.

Let $z = Py$, where $y \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Our equation becomes
$$
D \nabla_z^T f = -(\nabla_z^T \phi) f
$$
where $\nabla_z^T$ means differentiation with respect to $z$. This equation can be written componentwise as
$$
\lambda_i \frac{\partial f}{\partial z_i} = -\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial z_i} f
$$
where $\lambda_i$ are the eigenvalues of $Q$ (which are the diagonal entries of $D$) and $z_i$ are the components of $z$.

The above componentwise equation suggests that we could try a solution of the form $f = k e^{-\phi / \lambda}$, where $\lambda = \lambda_1 \lambda_2 ... \lambda_n$. If you compute the derivative of this potential solution and plug it into our componentwise equation, you will see that it is indeed a solution. Therefore, our solution in the original variables $x$ is $f = k e^{-P^T \phi / \lambda}$, where the division and the exponential are performed componentwise.